# Como gerar uma sequencia de datas no r?

Tags: r

Como faço para gerar uma lista com datas, por exemplo, com início em 2011-07-01 e final em 2011-10-31 ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Através da função `seq`:

```
datas_dia    <- seq(from=as.Date("2011-07-01"), to=as.Date("2011-10-31"), by="day")

datas_semana <- seq(from=as.Date("2011-07-01"), to=as.Date("2011-10-31"), by="week")

datas_mes    <- seq(from=as.Date("2011-07-01"), to=as.Date("2011-10-31"), by="month")
```

em que

- `as.Date` converte a string para o formato data
- `seq` cria a sequência
- `from` diz onde a sequência começa
- `to` diz onde a sequência termina
- `by` determina do incremento da sequência (no meu exemplo, os incrementos são dia, semana e mês, respectivamente)

Comment: Obrigado. Essa sequência mensal era justamente onde eu mais estava me complicando. Tentei criar data sem os dias, apenas com ano e mês, mas não consegui.

Comment: Que bom que deu certo. Considere [votar e aceitar a minha resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta) se ela resolveu, de fato, o teu problema.